# Laravel 5.7: Construct a "Domain path" accessor by using a domains query to get a domain and it's parent ids recursively

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, recursive-query, laravel-5.7

This app allows users to nest domains. A domain is just an eloquent model with an id, a string column that is the domain name and a parent_id that links it to another domain as a "child" or "sub-domain". In theory a user could nest as deeply as need be. I'm attempting to construct a domain path accessor that will resemble a url. Something like. `ParentMostDomain/NextChildDomain/AnotherChildDomain/ChildMostdomain` with each of the parents of the domain just being the string name. On the model that the accessor will live, there is a `domain_id` stored that is the child-most domain and a relationship to access the full domain model. On the `Domain` model, I've created `parentDomain` and `parentDomainsRecursive` relationships like so:

```
/**
 * Relationship to the domain the Model is in relation to
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function parentDomain()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Domain::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}

/**
 * Recursive Parent Domains
 *
 * @return \App\Models\Domain
 */
public function parentDomainsRecursive()
{
    return $this->parentDomains()->with('parentDomainsRecursive');
}
```

And the the accessor has access to the domain: `$this->domain->parentDomainsRecursive`. Each Domain has a name and that is what I would use to construct the `domain_path` from Parent-most to child-most. This all feels right so far, but for some reason I can't wrap my head around looping through all of these nested domains, started with the child-most. Any thoughts would be hugely appreciated! My accessor (not pretty) so far:

```
/**
 * Domain Path Attribute
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getDomainPathAttribute()
{
    dd($this->domain->parentDomainsRecursive);
    $domainPath = '';
    foreach ($this->domain->parentDomainsRecursive as $domain) {
        if ($domain) {
            $domainPath . $domain->domain . '\\';
        }
    }

    return $domainPath . '//' . $this->domain->domain;
}
```

That `dd($this->domain->parentDomainsRecursive);` looks something like this:

```
"domain": {
    "id": "451d35ee-4690-45a7-944c-8804ecfb759a",
    "parent_id": "762db7de-0d01-4c87-95c5-b7bb52db3e38",
    "name": "Fundamental grid-enabled artificialintelligence",
    "created_at": "2019-01-16 21:54:53",
    "updated_at": "2019-01-16 21:54:53",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "parent_domains_recursive": {
        "id": "762db7de-0d01-4c87-95c5-b7bb52db3e38",
        "parent_id": "a441e544-649c-4df5-8b42-2e731b19a85a",
        "name": "Reduced modular budgetarymanagement",
        "created_at": "2019-01-16 21:54:52",
        "updated_at": "2019-01-16 21:54:52",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "parent_domains_recursive": {
            "id": "a441e544-649c-4df5-8b42-2e731b19a85a",
            "parent_id": null,
            "name": "Multi-lateral eco-centric orchestration",
            "created_at": "2019-01-16 21:54:52",
            "updated_at": "2019-01-16 21:54:52",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "parent_domains_recursive": null
        }
    }
}
```

The parent-most has a null `parent_id`. In the above example, the url I am looking to get with this accessor would be `Multi-lateral eco-centric orchestration/Reduced modular budgetarymanagement/Fundamental grid-enabled artificialintelligence`.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up solving this with a recursive method:

```
public function getDomainPath($domainId)
{
    $domain = Domain::findOrFail($domainId);
    if (is_null($domain->parent_id)) {
        return $domain->domain;
    }
    $path = $this->getDomainPath($domain->parent_id) . '/' . $domain->domain;
    return $path;
}
```

I then call the method in the accessor and pass the child-most domain id.